# Get image url from description rss ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, rss

I parse a rss file. In description tag i have also an image . How can i get it and displayed ?

I started to check if an url is in description with :

```
NSString *substring = @"http:";
NSRange textRange = [[item objectForKey:@"summary"] rangeOfString:substring];

if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"there is an url");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"there is not an url");
}
```

but i don't know how to get it

Comment: You should consider using `NSXMLParser`, and try to find any `<img>` inside your `description` tag. Trying to find text like that in HTML/XML code is prone to errors, you never know how the text will be formatted, if there are spaces or tabs, lowercase or uppercase, etc.

Comment: Parse your XML file, the above mentioned method is tedious and not recommended

Answer (score 1):

If you are hesitant in "xml parsing" then you can convert this xml to NSDictionary first using https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary then just operate it like normal NSDictionary